# iOS 8: Use dynamic row height with auto layout...but also make all cells the same height

Tags: uitableview, autolayout

I have a UITableView with four rows. My four cells all have a different amount of multi-line content in them. Of course I like having auto layout determine the optimal height of each cell...but I'd like each of the four cells to be the same height, that height being the height of the *tallest* of the cells.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible yes, but you'll need to do the calculation then reload the tableView instead of letting `heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` take care of it for you...

For example

```
-(CGFloat)findGreatestCellHeight
{
    CGFloat height = 0.0f;

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < CELL_COUNT; i++) {

        NSString *text = [TEXT_ARRAY objectAtIndex:i];

// note WIDTH should match your cells textLabel width... Personally I'd explicitly set that in a custom UITableViewCell

        CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:THE_TEXTLABELS_FONT constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(WIDTH, HUGE_VALF) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping]; 


        if (textSize.height > height)
            height = textSize.height;
    }

    return height;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it wouldn't be ideal for larger sets of data, but for 4 cells I think it's ok.

Comment: The main problem is that my calculation isn't as simple as just computing the size of one label. There are multiple multi-line labels, with variable amounts of space between them...it's just fraught with problems, trying to calculate that independently of auto-layout.